# WP Как добавить класс если отсутствует контент?

Tags: wordpress

Есть необходимость в добавлении класса `'header_dark'` к тегу `<body>` при условии что в контенте **отсутствует тег** `<section>` Вот написал вот такой код, но он не работает.

```
function add_dark_class_to_head() {
    if (is_singular()) {
        $post_content = get_post_field('post_content', get_the_ID());
        $main_section_pattern = '/<main\b[^>]*>(.*?)<section\b[^>]*>/s';

        if (preg_match($main_section_pattern, $post_content)) {
            add_filter('body_class', function ($classes) {
                $classes[] = 'header_dark';
                return $classes;
            });
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_dark_class_to_head');
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? Что я не так проверяю ? *Контент сохраняеться в стандартные таблицы `WP` и задаеться через `Classic Editor`

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover"><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
    </header>
    <main id="main" class="main">
```

page.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="container">
    <div id="content" class="col_content">
        <div <?php post_class('post section py-md') ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

    <div class="title">
        <?php am_the_custom_title('h1'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="entry">
        <?php the_content(__('Read more', 'am')); ?>
        <div class="clear clearfix"></div>
        <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<div class="page-link"><p><span>' . __('Pages:', 'am') . '</span>', 'after' => '</p></div>')); ?>
        <?php edit_post_link(__('Edit', 'am'), '<br /><p>', '</p>'); ?>
    </div>

</div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

footer.php

```
</main>
<footer class="page-footer"></footer>
</div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Потому что в условии должно быть отрицание `if (!preg_match($main_section_pattern, $post_content))`. И не совсем понимаю зачем в ругулярном выражении тег `main` если Вам нужен только `section`.

Comment: По возможности лучше использовать [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Использую такую проверку, поскольку тег <section> в теории может встречаться и в <aside> <footer> ... Чтобы себя как-то ограничить. Что-то пока не сработало.  Код отрабатывает и когда есть тег и когда нету. Может что-то не так в регулярке ?

Comment: Пробовал ещё так $main_section_pattern = '/<main\b[^>]*>.*?<section\b[^>]*>.*?<\/section>.*?<\/main>/s';  Но тоже не работает.

Comment: А откуда `aside` и `footer` может взяться в `post_content`?

Comment: Ну и на счет регулярки, попробуйте `'/<main\b[^>]*>(?:(?!<main).)*<section\b[^>]*>/s'`

Comment: Вроде должно работать [https://onlinephp.io/c/1433a](https://onlinephp.io/c/1433a)

Comment: Да, действительно регулярное выражение рабочее. Как и мой вариант, https://onlinephp.io/c/c2e23  Но вот в WP оно почему-то не отрабатывает как надо и классы не добавляет при отсуцтвии секций

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147885/discussion-between-simon-and-blackstar1991).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот код:

```php
/**
 * Add body class when a section exists in the post.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function add_dark_class_to_head() {
    if ( ! is_singular() ) {
        return;
    }

    $post_content = get_post_field( 'post_content', get_the_ID() );

    if ( preg_match( '#<section.+?</section>#is', $post_content ) ) {
        return;
    }

    add_filter(
        'body_class',
        static function ( $classes ) {
            $classes[] = 'header_dark';

            return $classes;
        }
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_dark_class_to_head' );
```

Comment: К сожалению, представленый код не работает. При отсуцтвии `<section>` в `<main>` класс оно не добавляет. Возможно тут что-то не так с хуками обработки ?

Comment: Код точно работает - я его дебажил :))

Comment: Данные я даже привел для тестирования - можно ими поиграться и увидеть, что код работает.

Comment: Я понимаю, для `php` оно работает. Вопрос почему в WordPress вставляя в `functions.php` код не срабатывает. Все по стандарту, данные сохраняються в `wp_posts` хранятся в столбце `post_content` этой таблицы. Оно не добавляет нужный класс при отсуцтвии

Comment: Не так вставляете, не туда. Я тестировал в WordPress этот код, само собой. Где бы я взял add_action(), get_post_field() и прочее в голом PHP?

Comment: Да действительно. Но код не работает, если в контексте нету `<main></main>`..... Тоесть вот реальный проект с файлом `header.php` . Добавил в начало вопроса.

Comment: Вы же с самого начала в вопросе говорили про `<main>` и `<section>` - вот я сделал код под них. Теперь main не нужен? Но в вопросе вы опять используете `<main>` . Вы дайте четкий пример того. что у вас возвращает `get_post_field('post_content'...`.  И там точно не будет никакого main. потому что он выводится в header.

Comment: В связи с тем, что выяснилось, что у вас main выводится в header, я поправил код.

Comment: Возможно действительно мой косяк в постановке вопроса. Я имел ввиду, что в базе данных мы не храним тег `<main>`  но при генерации страницы он присуцтвует всегда. А вот `<section>`  может присуцтвовать или отсуцтвовать, но всегда в этом теге. (попробовал с примера убрать первую проверку на `<main>`, проблему не решило

Comment: Да, спасибо, теперь работает.

Answer (score -2):

В целом у вас должна отработать даже эта регулярка `#<main .*?</section#s` при условии валидной верстки. Если верстка может быть не валидной, то нужно исправлять верстку. Это первый момент, который заключается в том, что ваша логика уже должна была заработать.

Далее нужно разобраться с wordpress. `get_post_field` получает контент поста и фильтрует его для вывода на экран, по умолчанию `display` третьим аргументом там идет. То есть в таких ситуациях нужно задать себе четыре вопроса:

1. Я получу контент в хуке `wp_head`?
2. Я получаю в нужном мне формате от `get_post_field`? Там точно ничего не экранируется?
3. Регулярное выражение точно работает на тех данных, которые я получаю от пункта 2?
4. Я точно могу воздействовать на хук `body_class` в этом месте?

Что касается самой логики, а вы вообще уверены, что у вас всегда будет темная тема при отсутствии тега `<section>`? Вы точно уверены, что такое поведение не изменится в будущем и это не приведет к трудноуловимым багам? Вы точно хотите похоронить этот тег в светлой теме?)) Вы готовы к тому, чтобы обходить вывод каждой вашей статьи регулярным выражением вместо того, чтобы просто вывести контент? То есть сперва нужно ответить на эти вопросы, а потом решить задачу.

Вы можете пойти по другому пути и создать мета поле для постов назвав его `dark-theme` и сделав переключателем. Ну и еще я уверен 50+ вариантов решения этой задачи найдется без использования вот этих костылей

Comment: 8 вопросов и ни одной рекомендации на тему "WP Как добавить класс если отсутствует контент". Это не ответ, а длинный и бесполезный комментарий. Прежде чем писать ответ, надо потрудиться и самому себе ответить на первые 4 вопроса, создав и продебажив минимальный тестовый пример. Сделайте хоть что-то для автора вопроса, кроме пространных рассуждений. Тем самым вы окажете ему посильную помощь, что и является целью StackOverflow.

Comment: но эти вопросы важны, рекомендация дана в последнем абзаце